# mCrypton - does anyone know where I can find test vectors or a reference implementation?

Tags: block-cipher, test-vectors, lightweight

I am currently writing an implementation of the mCrypton lightweight block cipher (as presented in [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11604938_19)). Unfortunately, the authors do not provide any test vectors. I tried to contact the authors via e-mail, but did not receive an answer, and I had no luck googling for test vectors or a reference implementation.

Is anyone here on Crypto Stackexchange aware of a reference implementation or test vectors for mCrypton? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: While we cannot recommend you an implementation (it is off-topic), we certainly _may_ be able to provide test vectors (if somebody has them, but it is on-topic at least).

Comment: Alright, didn't know that recommending a (reference) implementation is off-topic. I'm just looking for something to test my own implementation against, so test vectors would be perfectly fine.